# Automatically creating schema in Nodejs using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a react+node app. I am using sequelize to create tables. I want sequelize to automatically create the **schema(not the tables, the tables are being automatically created if not present already)** in mysql and also populate one of the tables with a particular set of data.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('myschema','username','pass',{
    dialect:'mysql',
    host:'localhost'
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

The tables are automatically created but I want to create the schema - 'myschema' automatically as well, once I run the app (so as to avoid manually creating the schema in production).

```
router.post('/somepath',(req,res,next)=>{
const 
pathname=path.join(__dirname,'../','somefile.xlsx');
  let workbook=xlsx.readFile(pathname);
  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  var data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);//This is an array of json objects

//updating the database.

});
```

I want to populate the profile table with data from the array of json objects on startup **if not there already**.

Comment: Can u kindly explain what is the difference between the 2 situations by giving an example.

Comment: Right now, I have to manually create the schema from the workbench and also I do not know how to export the data in the excel file to the database at startup.

What I want is that whenever I start the server, the schema should be created and the excel data should be uploaded automatically, if not already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto)npm . It is helpful to generate schema and models from the DB.

- You will need to install the correct dialect binding globally before using sequelize-auto.  In your case it will be

```
npm install -g mysql
```

- Run following command

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -o [/path/to/models] -t [tableName]
```

If you want to generate for all tables then skip the last part i.e. -t [tableName] flag
For more details please refer the NPM's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is for creating multiple rows in a table at server startup

```
sequelize_object.sync() // is invoked at server startup
.then(res=>{
        const pathname=path.join(__dirname,'somepath','somefile.xlsx');
        let workbook=xlsx.readFile(pathname);
        var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

        var data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);//array of json objects

        usertable.bulkCreate(data) //using sequelize to create multiple rows
        .then(response=>{console.log("Records Imported")})
        .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
        console.log(res.data);
})
.catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
})
```